# C++ static code analysis that can be run in a TFS 2010 build?

Tags: c++, static-analysis

I'm looking for a native C++ static analysis tool that I can use both from within Visual Studio and as part of a TFS 2010 build.  It must also work for 64-bit compilation.  Does anyone know any tools that support this?

Answer (score 2):

I am using [CppCheck](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page).

This is a commandline tool which we use in our continous integration server, but I'm sure it can be called from a pre/post build event. It outputs to console or file (text/xml).

Comment: If it's a Commandline tool, then it can be easily incorparated in TFS2010 build.

Comment: I'm taking a look at it, but it doesn't seem to detect very many things.

Comment: maybe you can add to your question what exactly you're looking for?

Comment: I'm figuring that out as I go.  I'm evaluating tools now and what I'm hoping to get here are working solutions that other people know about or have tried.  CppCheck is a possibility so I gave you a +1.

Answer (score 1):

See our [SD C++ CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone) tool, which detects cloned code in spite of changes to layout, variable names and often even replaced statements.

This tool can be launched from a command line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about 64-bit compilation. But, I think can use FxCop for static code analysis of C++ projects by integrating FxCop into VS2010 project, run fxcopcmd.exe in the post-build event to automatically perform code analysis when building projects (or) you can use Invoke Process Activity in Build process Template.

Comment: I'm looking for something that can handle native C++.  FxCop cannot handle this.

Answer (score 0):

According to this blog, Visual Studio 11 will support 64-bit code analysis out-of-the-box in all editions:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2012/03/09/what-s-new-in-code-analysis-for-visual-studio-11.aspx